# UTF-8 encoding works with Cake 1.3.11, but it doesn't with Cake 2.2.3

Tags: cakephp, utf-8, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have a running CakePHP 1.3.11 project and all special chars (like äüöß) looks fine. On the same machine and sharing exactly the same database, I have also a Cake 2.2.3 project and here all special chars are messed up.

Settings for both projects are basically the same:

**core.php**

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

**database.php**

```
'encoding' => 'utf-8' # Cake 1.3.11
'encoding' => 'utf8'  # Cake 2.2.3 (utf-8 doesn't work with 2.2.3)
```

**View/Layouts/default.ctp**

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    ...
```

I also tried adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to **bootstrap.php**, but still not working.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the encoding of the files of the 2.2.3 project?

Comment: You mean the .php and .ctp files? Checked all relevant files and they are all UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant because I've seen some problems related to that before.

Comment: Did you verify they're encoded correctly in the database? I remember I had a problem where the characters were double encoded for some reason with Cake 1.3. When I upgraded to 2.0+ I had to fix all the database encodings.

Comment: It has always been `utf8` for the database.php file. always.

Comment: Dunno why the 1.3 project had 'utf-8' and not 'utf8'. If I remove the utf8 form my 2.2.3 project, then everything works fine. But it also means, that my database is messed up :( ... Thanks!